# Problemas en el login de mi pagina en asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, login

Tengo sistema en asp.net en un servidor local y quisiera implementar un login pero soy nuevo en esto asi que realice un login sensillo, este funciona pero al momento de ingresar se guarda en el servidor y cualquiera que vea la pagina ya no necesita hacer el login. Si alguien pudiera ayudarme a que no pasara eso o a realizar un mejor login.

La pagina esta con una pagina maestra la cual tiene que al cargar compruebe el login.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    carga();
}
private void carga()
{
    datlogin dat = new datlogin();
    bool prueba = dat.veri;
    if(prueba == false)
    {
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
    }
    else { LBL_Nombre.Text = dat.nom; LBL_apellido.Text = dat.apel; }

}
protected void cerrar(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    datlogin dat = new datlogin();
    bool sesion = dat.veri;
    if(sesion==true)
    {
        dat.veri = false;
        dat.id = ""; dat.nom = ""; dat.apel = "";
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
    }
}
```

El sigueinte es el codigo de la pagina login.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void btnIngresar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comprobacion();
}

private void comprobacion()
{
    string usua = TXT_Usuario.Text;
    string clav = TXT_clave.Text;
    datlogin dat = new datlogin();
    dat.usu = usua;
    dat.pas = clav;
    logindat log = new logindat();
    if (dat.veri == true) { alert.Visible = false; Response.Redirect("Default.aspx"); }
    else { alert.Visible = true; }
}
```

La clase datlogin donde se almacenan los datos de la sesion.

```
private static string Usuario = string.Empty;
private static string Password = string.Empty;
private static bool verifica = false;
private static string Nombre = string.Empty;
private static string Apellido = string.Empty;
private static string ID = string.Empty;


public string usu
{get { return Usuario; } set { Usuario = value; }}

public string pas
{get { return Password; } set { Password = value; }}

public bool veri
{get { return verifica; } set { verifica = value; }}

public string nom
{get { return Nombre; }set { Nombre = value; }}

public string apel
{get { return Apellido; } set { Apellido = value; }}

public string id
{get { return ID; } set { ID = value; }}
```

La clase logindat donde asigno los datos a la clase datlogin.

```
public logindat()
{
    verificacion();
}
string usua;
string clave;
private void verificacion()
{
    datlogin dat = new datlogin();
    usua = dat.usu;
    clave = dat.pas;

    Datos his = new Datos();
    DataTable tabla = new DataTable();
    string id = "";
    string nombre = "";
    string apellidos = "";
    try
    {
        tabla = his.iniciar("datosusu");
        id = tabla.Rows[0]["id_usuario"].ToString();
        nombre = tabla.Rows[0]["nombre"].ToString();
        apellidos = tabla.Rows[0]["apellidos"].ToString();
    }
    catch { }
    string id2 = "0";
    string nom = "No existe";
    string ape = "No existe";



    if (id != id2 && nombre!=nom && apellidos!=ape && id != "" && nombre != "" && apellidos != "")
    {
        dat.veri = true;
        dat.id = id;
        dat.nom = nombre;
        dat.apel = apellidos;
    }
    else { dat.veri = false; dat.id = ""; dat.nom = ""; dat.apel = ""; }

}
```

La clase datos donde obtengo la informacion de la base de datos.

```
SqlConnection conn;

public Datos()
{
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder sb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    sb["Data Source"] = "10.0.0.77";
    sb["Initial Catalog"] = "BDprueba";
    sb["Persist Security Info"] = "True";
    sb["User ID"] = "sa";
    sb["Password"] = "123456";
    conn = new SqlConnection(sb.ConnectionString);
}
    public DataTable iniciar(string tabla)
{
    datlogin log = new datlogin();
    string usua = log.usu;
    string clav = log.pas;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string sql = "";
    switch (tabla)
    {
        case "datosusu":
            sql = "execute verificacion '"+usua+"','"+clav+"'";
            break;
        default:
            dt.Columns.Add("id_usuario");
            dt.Columns.Add("nombrer");
            dt.Columns.Add("apellidos");
            dt.Rows.Add("0", "No existe","No existe");
            break;
    }
    if (sql != "")
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();//conjunto de tablas virtuales
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
            da.Fill(ds);
            if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                dt = ds.Tables[0];
        }
        catch
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("id_usuario");
            dt.Columns.Add("nombrer");
            dt.Columns.Add("apellidos");
            dt.Rows.Add("0", "No existe", "No existe");
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Codigo del proceso almacenado verificacion en Microsoft SQL Server.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[verificacion] 
@usuario nvarchar(50),
@clave nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
if @clave=(select clave from tbl_usuarios where usuario=@usuario)
begin
select tbl_usuarios.id_usuario,tbl_empleados.nombre,tbl_empleados.apellidos from tbl_usuarios LEFT JOIN tbl_empleados on tbl_usuarios.empleado=tbl_empleados.id_empleado where usuario=@usuario and clave=@clave
end
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas hacer una session de la aplicacion, asp.net ya tiene
un modo de hacerlo a su manera, aqui te dejo una documentacion de
como hacerlo.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/6e9y4s5t(v=vs.140)

solo remplazas tus valores
aqui tu conexion a bd

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySqlConnection" connectionString="Data 
      Source=MySqlServer;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;Integrated
      Security=SSPI;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

y aqui el form de donde haces el login

```
<authentication mode="Forms" >
  <forms loginUrl="login.aspx"
    name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por responder, ya leí la documentación pero no me queda muy claro, voy a seguir leyendo los enlaces que contiene pero si pudieras explicarme un poco mas.

Comment: esto lo ocupas para una futura aplicacion o solo estas probando????

Comment: necesito implementarlo pero por el momento estoy realizando pruebas antes de modificar el sistema

Comment: De la manera que lo estas haciendo te va dar muchos dolores de cabeza, te recomiendo que uses otra forma de autentificarte, hechale un ojo a esto https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api aunque microsoft casi nunca ayuda, capaz te ayuda en algo